# SQL code toggles between the value 1 and NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable1]
SET [MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated] = 
        CASE WHEN [MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated] IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN [MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated] = 0 THEN 1
        END
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable1]
INNER JOIN [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable2] mt2 WITH(NOLOCK)
ON mt2.[AN ID] = [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable1].[AN ID]
WHERE dm.[ANOTHER ID] = '1234'
```

This column can contain NULL, 0, 1, 2, or 3.

When I run this SQL it changes NULL, 0, 2, and 3 to 1 and it changes 1 to NULL.  If I run it again it changes 1 to NULL and NULL to 1.  (This is T-SQL in SQL Server 11.)

I am confused as to why it is exhibiting this behavior.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about doing this instead:

SET [MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated],0)=0 THEN 1
                                         ELSE ...
                                         END

Comment: What behavior did you actually expect and why?

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I expected the 1 to stay 1, the 2 and 3 to stay 2 and 3 respectively, and for NULL and 0 to be set to 1.

Comment: Of course you could also add to the `where` clause:`... and Coalesce( [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated], 0 ) = 0` to skip the rows that don't need to be updated. Perhaps there is a trigger you want to fire for the "do nothing" rows? Or there is more going on than your code sample shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's alternating is because of your `CASE` statement. There is no `ELSE` nor `DEFAULT` clause, so when the column doesn't match any of your conditions, the value is set to `NULL`. When the update runs again, `NULL` is a case that's handled, so the value gets set to 1.

Comment: Thank you.  I added ELSE [MyTable1].[Column To Be Updated] and now it is behaving as I wanted it to.